# How to use a component which starts disable but has to start enable?

Tags: javascript, angular, web-component

I have aN autocomplete componenent at my application which starts disable. It's a component which is called in a lot of place at my application.

**COMPONENT AUTOCOMPLETE**

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.internalForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      value: [null]
    });
    this.internalForm.get('value').disable();   }
```

I need to start the componenent enable this time.

I already tried:

**ANOTHER COMPONENET**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.carregarDropDowns();
    this.form.get('cboControl').enable();
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Need to see the code for `this.form` and `this.carregarDropdowns`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have an @Input property in your first component and disable your autocomplete based on the input option value. e.g.

```
@Component({
   selector: 'auto-complete',
   templateUrl: 'auto-complete.component.html'
})
export class AutoCompleteComponent {
  @Input() enabled: boolean;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.internalForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      value: [null]
    });

    if (!this.enabled) {
        this.internalForm.get('value').disable();
    }
}
```

Then you can pass enabled flag to it when you want it enabled.

```
<auto-complete enabled="true"></auto-complete>
```

**Edit:** Changing the code example to avoid changing old code as per requested in comment

Comment: The problem is, I don't want to change anything at my Autocomplete component, because if I do that, I will have a lot of code to change.
I'm looking for something to do at my component.

Comment: You can instead make an @Input called enabled and pass true to it where you want to enable the autocomplete. That way you won't have to change code anywhere else and in autocomplete component you can enable based on passed value like if(!this.enabled) { // disable autocomplete }. That way enabled will be undefined for your old implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that I understand your problem correctly, but you could simply use a `@Input` to solve your problem:

**autocomplete.component.ts**

```
export class AutoCompleteComponent {
    @Input() disable = true;    
    ...

    ngOnInit() {
        this.internalForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            value: [null]
        });
        if (this.disable) {
            this.internalForm.get('value').disable();   
        }
    }
}
```

And in your other component simply:

```
<auto-complete-component [disable]="false" ...></auto-complete-component>
```

Comment: The problem is, I don't want to change anything at my Autocomplete component, because if I do that, I will have a lot of code to change.
I'm looking for something to do at my component.

Comment: Why do you have a lot of code changes? I see in my approach only changes in 4 lines. With set `disabled` as default to `true` you don't need to change any of your component, which are disabled by default.